# Wired and wireless mDNS/Avahi discovery (Google Home/Chromecasts)

Tags: networking, mdns, avahi

My network looks like this:

[ pfSense Router ] - [ TP-SG3210 Switch ] - [ Netgear R7800 running OpenWrt ]

The R7800 is running as an AP. No VLANs.

Wired:

- nVidia Shield TV
- Ubuntu Server

Wireless:

- MacBook Pro
- Samsung S8
- Google Home
- Nexus Player

The R7800 is running Avahi.

The MacBook can see / cast to everything - the Shield, the Nexus Player, Google Homes...

My S8 can see all other devices that are wireless: the Nexus Player, the Google Homes. It cannot see the Shield TV.

My Ubuntu server has Home Assistant running, and it's 'discovery' component cannot find *any* devices, wired or wireless.

I'm a loss for how to troubleshoot this. Do I need avahi running on every host? (i.e. the server too?)

Comment: In a typical mDNS implementation on a host, a single daemon is used for all the mDNS traffic being sent or received by the whole host. So all advertising and discovering / querying / browsing goes through that daemon. So if you want the Ubuntu server to be able to discover or be discovered, it must be running an mDNS implementation of some sort.

Comment: Thanks, Spiff. I encountered the daemon not running message when I tried to `avahi-browse` on my Ubuntu server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My switch was causing the problem: [TP-Link DoS protection blocks Bonjour](https://superuser.com/questions/1218278/tp-link-dos-protection-blocks-bonjour)

I had been thinking that I had not configured bridged AP mode in OpenWRT but that was a red herring. I used `dns-sd` from my MacBook and `avahi-browse -t -a` from Ubuntu, OpenWrt and the pfSense Router. It was then I realized that I could not discover from pfSense <-> OpenWrt nor pfSense <-> Ubuntu nor Ubuntu <-> OpenWrt

As soon as I turned of DDoS Defend on the TG-SG3210 I was able to see everything, my Google Home app found everything, etc. etc.